# CSS flexbox borders on mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, mobile-safari

I am making a small html/css/js game that consists on a board with several tiles and a small character that can move on them. The board is made with divs using css flexbox.

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell green"></div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

On desktop browsers like Chrome or Firefox it looks great. But on mobile (iOS Safari/Chrome and Android Chrome) it shows kind of a border. The most odd thing is that it isn't completely regular :S

[image]

I have set up a jsfiddle so you can see it:

https://jsfiddle.net/igorosabel/jjy1ok3c/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a litlle shadow to hide that gap :

```css
.board{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.row{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.cell{
  flex: 1;
}

.grass{
  background-color: #489848;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #489848; /* because of a white gap that can show on small screens */
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
    <div class="cell grass"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjy1ok3c/3/

*edit: i already answered this else where on SO, but could not find the dupliicate* [image: screenshot android]

Comment: Nice try, it gets better but still no fix: [link](http://i.imgur.com/YnORmbT.png) I looked for answers on this but didn't find any, if you have the answer I would gladly close this question :) thanks @GCyrillus

Comment: @IñigoGorosabel make the shadow unblured : `box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #489848;` https://jsfiddle.net/jjy1ok3c/3/ if the trick is fine with you. You can add overflow:hidden; on parent if you mind that extra pixel